# Add List to MutableLiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, architecture, android-livedata

I have a `MutableLiveData` and I want to add a `List` inside, but seems the below code doesn't work:

```
    private var factsLive: MutableLiveData<List<Fact>>? = null

private fun getObserver(): SingleObserver<List<Fact>> {
    return object : SingleObserver<List<Fact>> {
        override fun onSuccess(t: List<Fact>) {
            Log.d("test", "Succes")
            factsLive?.value = t
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
            Log.d("test", "Subscribe")
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Log.d("test", "Error")
        }
    }
}
```

This returns me `MutableLiveData` like null.

Comment: you need `private val factsLive = MutableLiveData<List<Fact>>()`

Comment: Make sure `t` received in `onSuccess()` is not null

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Thanks so much, you solve my problem but can you explain me the reason why my method didn't work?

Comment: @David because `factsLive` hadn't been initialised and was still set to `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your variable like this:

```
private var factsLive: MutableLiveData<List<Fact>> = MutableLiveData<>()
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me, but when I use 'ArrayList' it does not properly work ( . interesting